# How can i get the elements in the form has the data type with value as true..?

Tags: jquery

i tried like this, but not work:

```
var elements = form.children().find($.data('required', true));

 $('#contactForm').submit(function(event){

          $(elements).each(function(){
               console.log($(this));     
          })

          return false;
     })
```

is this wrong, any one correct me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation for `jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data), you'll see if does *nothing* like what you're asking it to.

The best thing to do would be to `filter()` your form elements;

```
var elements = form.find(':input').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('required') === true;
});
```

See the documentation for [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter). Also note `$().data()` differs from `jQuery.data()`.

Comment: it needs all elements, encluding select, textarea and whatever the form elements..

Comment: ... which is exactly what [`:input` gives you](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/). What's the problem?

Comment: it means that, will it include all form elements? let me try.. because i am making form validation, so the user if adds the data as required i need to validate

Answer (score 0):

Should do it:

```
var elements = form.children().find('*[data-required=true]');
```

Comment: elements.length return's 0;